# Blender 2.8 crashes when entering particle edit

Tags: particles, hair

Blender 2.8 is crashing when I try to go into particle edit to comb hair.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case it helps someone: if you have a baked hair simulation and try to go into particle edit (i.e., combing) without deleting the bake first, it will crash blender.